# How to convert string to integer in MASM

Tags: string, parsing, integer, masm

I want to simply get the user to input a number. I can get input (I think), but this is a string, and I need to convert it to a number (DWORD). I couldn't find anything that worked in MASM. I tried the C functions strtol and atoi, but it couldn't find them. Is there some function that works in MASM? Or do I have to write my own conversion?

I tried several include files, but I couldn't get the C functions:
windows.inc
kernel32.inc
user32.inc
msvcrt.inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `atoi PROTO C strptr:DWORD` and then I was able to call `atoi`.

Answer (score 1):

Its over 20 years since I used MASM so I'm a bit rusty. The algorithm is pretty straightforward though.

- Assuming your string is in ASCII
- Start at the end of the string
- You will need to split each character off the string and subtract 30H from it to give the digit
- store that digit in a register
- calculate your next power of ten
- Each time you move one character left and get that digit multiply by the next power of ten
- add to accumulator

E.g for an integer

31H 32H 33H

31h-30H = 1H
32H-30H = 2H * 10
33H-30H = 3H * 10 * 10

Bingo!

If the number represents a double you will need to cope with in a similar manner.

Comment: sooo... there's no function to do it for me?

Comment: If you want to call atoi you would need to include the C runtime libraries rather than the Windows libraries

Comment: Would that be msvcrt.lib? I tried both the .lib and the .inc, but it said undefined symbol. Maybe it is in the .lib but not the .inc, and I need to proto define it.

Comment: Ok, I went `atoi PROTO C strptr:DWORD` and includelib'ed msvcrt.lib and it worked!